# How can you pass props and use HOC with React context

Tags: reactjs

I need to do something like this

```
const CreateActivity = (props) => (
<AuthUserContext.Consumer>
  {authUser =>
    <CreateActivityShow  email={authUser.email} {...props}/>
  }
</AuthUserContext.Consumer>

const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;
export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(CreateActivity);
```

this way I'm using my HOC component correctly with createActivity but on  CreateActivityShow this.props only has this.props.email and not url parameters I should have with this.props.match...

I tried this way

```
  export default props =>  (
<AuthUserContext.Consumer>
  {authUser =>
    <CreateActivityShow {...props} email={authUser.email}/>
  }
</AuthUserContext.Consumer>
)
```

now I have the props, but I don't know how can I use my HOC here

is there a way to do both at same time?

edit:

I've tried this

```
 export default withAuthorization(authCondition)( props =>  (
<AuthUserContext.Consumer>
  {authUser =>
    <CreateActivityShow {...props} email={authUser.email}/>
  }
</AuthUserContext.Consumer>
))
```

Now I have again my component wrapped by withAuthorization, but props are not being passed now and I don't know why...

this is my HOC

```
const withAuthorization = (authCondition) => (Component) => {
  class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if (!authCondition(authUser)) {
        this.props.history.push(routes.SIGN_IN);
      }
    });
  }

render() {
  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
      {authUser => authUser ? <Component /> : null}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
  );
  }
}

return withRouter(WithAuthorization);
}

export default withAuthorization;
```

Comment: Can you show withAuthorization HOC. I assume the problem is there

Comment: added the code my withAuthorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, so the problem is in the `WithAuthorization` component where you are not passing the props received by HOC to the Component that is rendered. You would write it like

```
const withAuthorization = (authCondition) => (Component) => {

    class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
          if (!authCondition(authUser)) {
            this.props.history.push(routes.SIGN_IN);
          }
        });
      }

        render() {
          return (
            <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
              {authUser => authUser ? <Component {...this.props}/> : null}
            </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
          );
        }

    }

    return withRouter(WithAuthorization);
}

export default withAuthorization;
```